# Why can't I view Chinese characters correctly in a dbf file?

Tags: mysql, dbf, chinese-locale

I'm trying to import data from a dbf to a database, and everything is fine, except the column with Chinese characters.

However, rather than it being a problem to do with the import process, I suspect that the source file itself is problematic. I've also heard that people have no problem doing exactly the same thing in Windows, because the dbf file shows Chinese characters correctly, but it just shows a bunch of weird characters on OS X.

Here's a screenshot of how it appears with TextEdit:

[image]

Here's a screenshot after importing to a MySQL database:

[image]

I would appreciate any help and thoughts regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properly constructed `dbf` files have an embedded field that contains the encoding of the character fields.  A text editor will have no clue about that.  MySQL should, but may not (I'm not an MySQL user, so don't know).

Assuming the `dbf` is properly constructed you could use a dbf exporter program to create a utf-8 text file with the data, and import that.

If you are able to use [Python](https://www.python.org/) you could use my [dbf module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf) to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Ethan is right - MySQL have no idea that the characters you're trying to import are Chinese. I think the possible solution is to convert all characters of the DBF file to UTF-8 encoding (which is native for MySQL), then export it to a MySQL database.

The possible way is to use [DBF Commander Pro](http://dbf-software.com) editor. Open the DBF file, click '*File -> Convert -> ANSI to UTF-8*'. More info on conversion routine is available [here](http://dbf-software.com/dbf-file.html#Convert).

After the conversion, try to [import](http://dbf-software.com/dbf-file.html#ImpExpDBMS) the DBF file to a MySQL database with DBF Commander Pro, or with the tool you've used previously.

Fully functional 30-day trial of the program allows you to do the task for free.